# Does the CLR target the OS or the hardware?

Tags: .net-framework

When you run an exe using .net, I know that the exe itself targets the CLR. But the code that comes out of the CLR targets the OS or directly the hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a regular compiler, it targets both – it generates machine code that is run directly by the CPUs while using OS features (like the filesystem or user interface APIs).